# PHP or Laravel caching Server Side Code?

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I have this strange issue. My server side code is being cached by something i dont know what.

This is my route : `Route::get('GlCountry/{country}', 'CashHoldingController@GetGlByCountry');`

`CashHoldingController` had some functions but i deleted the entire file so now is empty and my application is still using the functions that i deleted... is like they are there but dont.

My server is running under IIS7 and im using laravel 5.5

No matter what i do is like the controller code is being cached somewhere.

I've tried disabling `php opcache extension`  but still the same. I dont know what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried 'php artisan cache:clear' or 'php artisan route:clear
' ?

Comment: Yes @WouterVanDamme also i used `composer dump-autoload` and nothing....

Comment: What happens when you recreate the functions you deleted, put a dd(); in there, and try hitting the route again

Comment: Reload the php-server, that should do the trick

Comment: I dont know what happend but it is solved. I just stopped the IIS server, had lunch for 1 hour and started the server back. Now it is running all good.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the routes cache with this command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz try to manually delete the `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` file.

Comment: There is not a routes.php file there

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I think the problem is not in the cache then. Could you update your question with all routes and show me how do you execute this route (URL, link or form action)?